# The Organic Group membership Entries in the Registration form is showing all the translated entry

Tags: organic-groups

My Organic Group is translatable In several languages.

Right now, the problem is that If someone want to register on the website and this user is viewing the website in french, he seen all the organic group list in both languages.

How display only the French Entries ?

Thanks a lot